# Does the Order of the Silver Chalice still have a presence in Waterdeep?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist

I'm about to start running *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, and one of the characters is a Knight of the Silver Chalice. I believe that this organization was originally founded in Waterdeep. Do they still have a presence there (circa 1492 DR)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [Order of the Silver Chalice](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Silver_Chalice) is either no longer present in Waterdeep or they have gone into hiding.

Possible spoilers for *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* (p. 117):

> Their base, a secret temple of Siamorphe, was desecrated by Victoro and Ammalia [Cassalanter](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Cassalanter), and is now [Cassalanter Villa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/hell-of-a-summer#CassalanterVilla).

The only shrine to [Siamorphe](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Siamorphe) is the Chapel and Chalice of the Divine Right, in [Assumbar](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Assumbar) villa.

[Jeremy Crawford stated in a 2015 tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/01/02/siamorphe-and-the-knights-of-the-silver-chalice/) that "Siamorphe and the Knights of the Silver Chalice endure", but did not provide any additional details.