# Does the Order of the Aster still have a presence in Waterdeep?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist

I'm about to start running *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, and one of my characters is part of the Order of the Aster. What is their presence in Waterdeep (circa 1492 DR)? I was able to find some information about them in City of Splendors, so I guess my question is really whether that information is still relevant or if the Order's status has changed since then.

Comment: Your related question: [Does the Order of the Silver Chalice still have a presence in Waterdeep?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153783/does-the-order-of-the-silver-chalice-still-have-a-presence-in-waterdeep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As far as I know, no lore has been released about the Order of the Aster in 5th Edition.

I did search a lot of Wikis and all source books that I have access to (I don't have the modules, so I can't say if it is mentioned in the *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* or *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* adventures...) and I was unable to find anything post 1390 DR concerning the Order of the Aster.

I did go through the list of all "famous" members of the Order on all wikis that had one ... I'm thinking this specific Order has not been mentioned in 5e. But that certainly does not mean the Order does not exist anymore.

Comment: I can confirm that the term "Aster" is not mentioned anywhere in the 5e books: https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=aster (If relevant results search existed, you'd see them there, even if you can't access the full content of non-free material without owning it.)